# My new installed router is not working for online games?

Tags: networking, router

So with my router yesterday I can connect to LoL servers or Blizzard client etc... but now I installed my new router I can't...
It just says cannot connect to server or it just doesn't connect to server.. I don't know what I can do to fix this...
Can anyone help me out?~

My router is a TP link TD-W8960N

Answer (score 1):

Try this steps, execute one and test:

1. Check if router lights are indicating internet access;
2. Check if you have connect to the internet (access a site);
3. Check if your firewall or antivirus are blocking your application;
4. Reset your Router.